# How does the HTML5 multiple file upload field map to a nested model in Rails 3?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, formtastic

I'm trying to use the HTML5 multiple attribute on a file field in a nested form.

The models are as follows:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :album_images
  has_many :images, :through => :album_images

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images

end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :album_images
  has_many :albums, :through => :album_images

  mount_uploader :filename, ImageUploader

  validates_presence_of :filename

end
```

The view:

```
  <%= semantic_form_for @album, :url => upload_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs do %>
      <%= f.input :name, :label => 'Album title' %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.input :images, :as => :file, :input_html => {:multiple => true} %>

    <%= f.buttons do %>
      <%= f.commit_button 'Upload' %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

When I use for the file field:

```
<%= f.input :images, :as => :file, :input_html => {:multiple => true} %>
```

I get:

```
<input id="album_images" multiple="multiple" name="album[images][]" type="file">
```

Which doesn't doesn't seem right since *I think* I want to set the filename on the object directly, but I'm not sure about this.  When I try to upload with this field, the incoming params look like:

```
 "album"=>{"name"=>"2011-01-09", "images"=>["IMG_0052.JPG", "IMG_0053.JPG", "IMG_0054.JPG", "IMG_0055.JPG"]}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Image(#2157004660) expected, got String(#2151988680)):
```

OK, that error is probably due to the fact that it just received a filename and not an image object. So instead, I use for the file field:

```
<%= f.input :images, :as => :file, :input_html => {:multiple => true, :name => 'album[images][][filename]'} %>
```

for which Formtastic generates:

```
<input id="album_images" multiple="multiple" name="album[images][][filename]" type="file">
```

The incoming params look like:

```
"album"=>{"name"=>"2011-01-09", "images"=>[{"filename"=>"IMG_0052.JPG"}, {"filename"=>"IMG_0053.JPG"}, {"filename"=>"IMG_0055.JPG"}]}
```

But then I get this error:

```
Image(#2153868680) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#2158892780)
```

So how does one go about setting up this multiple file input filed mapping in Rails?

Thanks.

Comment: Downvoted because you never provided any feedback to the answer below and never came back to update your question if you had / hadn't resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `:html => { :multipart => true }` in your `form_for` (or in your case `semantic_form_for`) call so that your `<form>` tag is set to support file uploads.

**Then** revert back to your original syntax for `f.input` and you should be right then.