# Gems/plugins for uploading multiple files in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, upload, paperclip

Specifically, I would like to allow a user to upload up to 5 images. Any direction to a simple tutorial would be greatly appreciated. Ideally the data for the uploaded file would be stored in an existing database. I have tried paperclip, but I can't seem to get it to work with multiple files. I've also tried some other tutorials from 2008 that don't seem to work w/ rails 3.Thanks for the help!

I would prefer direction of tutorials that you have tried and worked.

Comment: Try plupload or try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643999/how-does-the-html5-multiple-file-upload-field-map-to-a-nested-model-in-rails-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I had the same problem yesterday, I wrote a tutorial about it: http://blog.powpark.com/2013/10/16/multiple-file-upload-with-html5-and-rails-admin/

Comment: Thank you for sharing this with us, Anton!

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the most popular file-upload gems is Carrierwave (https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave). There is also a demo app (https://github.com/kdironside/carrierwave-multi-file-upload) that specifically demonstrates uploading multiple files.

However, it's certainly possible to accomplish the same thing with Paperclip. Perhaps you can let us know what problem you ran into specifically, and we can help you out there.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I followed this tutorial: http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/paperclip-with-rails-3  and ran into this error : asset.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting tASSOC
...:medium => "300x300>", :thumb "100x100>" }

Comment: The tutorial also mentions the need to install image magic, which I am not familiar with. I think that I will try my luck with carrierwave and see how that works.

Comment: Sure. I think it will be helpful if you can post your Paperclip related code so we can check if there's an issue there.

Comment: Also, I think Carrierwave also depends on Imagemagick, but we can help you install that as well. (If you're on a Mac, check this out: http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/)